# Python3 - function signature indicates a return value, but without specifying the type

Tags: python-3.x, signature, typing

I would like to define a function such that the return value has a different type in different occasions.

Still, I would like to include in the function signature an indication that it returns *something*.

I know one way to do this is to use `Union`, for example:

```
from typing import Union

def f(x: int) -> Union[str, int]:
    return x if x > 0 else "this is zero"
```

But in my case, I don't have the list of possible output types at hand.

I tried to use:

```
def f(x: int) -> object:
    return some_other_func(x)
```

The problem is, that now when I try to use this function the IDE tells me I have a typing error:

```
y: SomeClass = f(42)
Error: Expected type 'SomeClass', got 'object' instead
```

So - how can I indicate in the function signature that `f` is returning *some* value, without indicating the *type* of the value?

Answer (score 0):

From the [typing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any), it is possible to use `Any`, for example:

```
from typing import Any

def f(x: int) -> Any:
    return some_other_func(x)
```